# Is it possible to create a template constructor for which "explicit" is added only for certain template parameters?

Tags: c++

Suppose that I have a `Ptr` type (a wrapper around a pointer), which has a move constructor:

```
template <typename OBJECT>
struct Ptr {
    Ptr() { }

    template <typename INIT>
    /*explicit*/ Ptr(Ptr<INIT> &&) { }
};
```

Now, I'd like to have both of these:

- If I set `Ptr` with another `Ptr`, for which `INIT==OBJECT` (or `INIT` is a derived type of `OBJECT`), then it must compile without any hassle
- If I set `Ptr` with another `Ptr`, for which `OBJECT` is a derived of `INIT`, then I must explicitly say the conversion.

So, I'd like to mirror the usual pointer behavior:

```
struct Base { };
struct Der: Base { };

int main() {
    Base *b;
    Der *d;

    b = d; // compiles fine
    d = static_cast<Der *>(b); // cast needed
}
```

So, in the case of `Ptr`:

```
Ptr<Base> fn(); // fn returns Ptr<Base>, for which the contained object is actually a Der

int main() {
    Ptr<Base> b = Ptr<Der>();    // compiles fine
    Ptr<Der> d = fn();           // should NOT compile
    Ptr<Der> d = Ptr<Der>(fn()); // I need to be explicitly convert Ptr<Base> to Ptr<Der> to compile
}
```

Is it possible to do this? I've tried SFINAE, but this doesn't compile (because the second move constructor is a re-declaration):

```
template <typename OBJECT>
struct Ptr {
    Ptr() { }

    template <typename INIT, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<INIT *, OBJECT *>>>
    Ptr(Ptr<INIT> &&) { }
    template <typename INIT, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_convertible_v<INIT *, OBJECT *>>>
    explicit Ptr(Ptr<INIT> &&) { }
};
```

The idea would be there that if `INIT *` is convertible to `OBJECT *`, then the constructor is not explicit, otherwise it is.

Comment: You mean like here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998807/constructor-conditionally-marked-explicit I imagine it's a problem of how your c'tors are defined.

Comment: Actually, the other post has just the same attempt. The solution there is to switch `typename = std::enable_if_t<>` into `std::enable_if_t<, bool> = false`. I imagine it's because the templates really cannot be checked for any sort of equivalence until used when it's done the right way.

Comment: Closed as a dupe. Almost the exact same problem, [and the same solution applies](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e42bd702380a358d).

Comment: @StoryTeller: Yep, thanks.

Comment: For further reference, here's a question about the difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499008/sfinae-works-differently-in-cases-of-type-and-non-type-template-parameters