# Are std::tuple and std::tuple<std::tuple> considered same type by std::vector?

Tags: c++, tuples

I have a variable defined like this

```
auto drum = std::make_tuple
          ( std::make_tuple
          ( 0.3f
          , ExampleClass
          , [](ExampleClass& instance) {return instance.eGetter ();}
          )
          );
```

I expect `drum` to be a tuple of tuple. (i.e. `((a, b, c))`).

And I have another variable defined like this

```
auto base = std::make_tuple
          ( 0.48f
          , ExampleClass
          , [](ExampleClass& instance) {return instance.eGetter ();}
          );
```

which I expect to be just a tuple of three elements (i.e `(a, b, c)`)

I also have a vector defined as follows

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::tuple< float
                                 , ExampleClass
                                 , std::function<float (ExampleClass&)>
                                 >>> listOfInstruments;
```

Now if I add `drum` to `listOfInstruments` I expect no errors.

Which was indeed the case with `listOfInstruments.push_back(drum);`

Where I expected an error was here `listOfInstuments.push_back(base);` but the code compiles just fine.

Since `listOfInstruments` has type 'tuple of tuples', should't adding just 'tuple' cause some error? Unless both `()` and `(())` are considered same types by `std::vector`. Or am I completely wrong and there's something else at work here?

Can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly discourage you from declaring a `std::tuple` of one element, and instead use the element type.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Tuples and vectors are mostly red herrings here. The way that works is simply that `push_back`, like any function, can perform implicit conversions on its argument, as demonstrated by the following working snippet:

```
#include <vector>

struct A { };

struct B {
    B(A const &) { }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<B> v;
    v.push_back(A{});
}
```

Going back to tuple, we can see that it has (among others) a conditionally-explicit constructor ([#2 here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple)) which takes references to the tuple's members-to-be:

```
tuple( const Types&... args );
```

This constructor is implicit if and only if all of the members have implicit copy constructors, which is the case here (as synthesized constructors are implicit indeed). This means that `std::tuple<...>` is implicitly convertible to `std::tuple<std::tuple<...>>`, which is what you're observing.

Comment: That constructor is "conditionally explicit"; you might want to explain why it is implicit in this case.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont uuuh... I had missed that note, but to be fair I don't understand why that is myself.

Comment: Perhaps a link to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32998807/1116364) about conditionally explicit constructors is helpful.

Comment: @DanielJour that's how one would go and implement such a constructor, but I don't get what types could possibly fail `std::is_convertible<const Ti&, Ti>` and why it would make sense for the constructor to be explicit in that case...

Comment: @Quentin I believe that would fail if `Ti`'s copy constructor were explicit. So that constructor is explicit if any of its members' copy constructors are explicit.

Comment: @DavidBrown D'oh! I was reading it backwards, trying to initialize `T const &` from `T`... That makes much more sense, thanks!