# How can I apply make a default constructor conditionally explicit?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae, explicit

### Problem

Suppose we have a (fictional) class template `C<T>` with a conditionally explicit default constructor. The default constructor should be explicit if and only if `std::is_same_v<T, int>`.

[A search on "[c++] conditionally explicit"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcpp%5D+conditionally+explicit) returns this result: [Constructor conditionally marked explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998807/constructor-conditionally-marked-explicit).

### A failed solution

The accepted answer gives an example:

> ```
> struct S {
>   template <typename T,
>              typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, bool>::type = false >
>   S(T) {}
>
>   template <typename T,
>             typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<T>::value, bool>::type = false>
>   explicit S(T) {}
> };
> ```

Modifying the example slightly gives this implementation which uses the familiar approach of `std::enable_if`:

```
template <class T>
class C {
public:
  template <std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int>, int> = 0>
  C() {}

  template <std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<T, int>, int> = 0>
  explicit C() {}
};
```

Unfortunately, this does not even compile: [<kbd>demo</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/l1jvTE07pXPBHTs0)

```
prog.cc: In instantiation of 'class C<int>':
prog.cc:15:10:   required from here
prog.cc:10:12: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, int>'
   10 |   explicit C() {}
      |            ^
prog.cc: In instantiation of 'class C<double>':
prog.cc:18:13:   required from here
prog.cc:7:3: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, int>'
    7 |   C() {}
      |   ^
```

The problem seems to be caused by the omission of a template parameter of the constructor, disabling SFINAE.

### Question

1. Why does this not compile?
2. What is a possible implementation?

I would like to avoid specializing the class if possible.

Comment: There is an option in c++20 of adding a condition to the explicit

Comment: [Something like this](https://godbolt.org/z/iEKwuz) ?

Comment: @BiagioFesta Thank you! Your solution worked for me. Can you write an answer and explain the details so I can accept it?

Comment: SFINAE only works when it depends on a template parameter.

Comment: @PasserBy Thank you for the "SFINAE only works when it depends on a template parameter" sentence! I guess that is the explanation I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 2. What is a possible implementation?

Have you tried with

```
template <class T>
class C {
public: //  VVVVVVVVVVVVVV .................................V  U here, not T
  template <typename U = T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<U, int>, int> = 0>
  C() {}

  template <typename U = T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<U, int>, int> = 0>
  explicit C() {}
};
```

?

> 1. Why does this not compile?

The problem is that SFINAE, over class methods, works with the template parameters of the methods itself.

That is in the original working code:

```
  template <typename T,
             typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, bool>::type = false >
  S(T) {}
```

where `T` is a template parameter specific of the constructor (deduced from the single argument).

On the contrary, in your failing code,

```
template <std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, int>, int> = 0>
C() {}
```

the constructors are evaluating the template parameter of the class (`T`), not of the methods.

With the trick `typename U = T`, you transform `T`, the template parameter of the class, in `U`, a template parameter of the methods (constructors in your case, but works also with other methods) so `std::enable_if_t`, with a test depending from `U`, is able to enable/disable the constructors.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! I have to admit that C++ template meta-programming is quite counter-intuitive at times ...

Comment: @L.F. - And this is nothing: if you try to enable/disable both constructors with `typename =  std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<U, int>` instead of `std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<U, int>, int> = 0`, you should get an error because the constructors collide.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I guess that’s more common so I happened to know it.