# No sutable conversion from vec2f to vec5f exists in custom math vector implementation

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Consider the following piece code of code

```
template <class T, size_t N,
         typename std::enable_if_t<(std::is_arithmetic_v<T> && N > 0), bool> = true>
class vec {
public:

    // ...

    template <class... U,
              typename std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(U) <= N &&
                                         (std::is_same_v<T, U> && ...)),
                                        bool> = true>
    explicit vec(U&&... args) : scalars({std::forward<T>(args)...}) {
    }

    template <class U, size_t M>
    explicit vec(const vec<U, M>& other) {
        std::copy(other.begin(), other.end(), begin());
    }

    template <class U, size_t M>
    auto& operator=(const vec<U, M>& other) {
        if (this == &other) return *this;
        std::copy(other.begin(), other.end(), begin());
        return *this;
    }

    // ...

    [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto begin() const noexcept { return scalars.begin(); }
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto begin() noexcept { return scalars.begin(); }
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto end() const noexcept { return scalars.end(); }
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto end() noexcept { return scalars.end(); }
private:
    std::vector<T, N> scalars{};
};
```

Trying to perform copy like this:

```
vec<float, 2> v2(0.1f, 0.3f);
vec<float, 5> v5 = v2;
```

results in error:
[*no suitable user-defined conversion from "vec<float, 2ULL>" to "vec<float, 5ULL>" exists*]

*Note: This is just the snippet of code. I know there are a lot of math libraries that implements math vectors way better, I wrote this just for learning. I know about rule of “The Rule of The Big Four (and a half)" but I don't know how to swap two std::arrays with different size.*

Comment: Constructors are explicit, so the initialization form should be `vec<float, 5> v5(v2);`.

Comment: Is there a way to have both explicit copy ctor and operator=?

Comment: You can use some metaprogramming to make your constructs [conditionally `explicit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998807/constructor-conditionally-marked-explicit).

Comment: *"Is there a way to have both explicit copy ctor and operator=?"* -- there is no `operator=` in your question, only conversion and construction. `vec<float, 5> v5 = v2;` performs an implicit conversion of `v2` to `vec<float, 5>` then constructs `v5` from that. To make use of `operator=` you would need two lines, as in `vec<float, 5> v5;` `v5 = v2;`.